# Operations on Python hashes

Tags: python, math, hash, dht, hashlib

I've got a rather strange problem. For a Distributed Hash Table I need to be able to do some simple math operations on MD5 hashes. These include a sum (numeric sum represented by the hash) and a modulo operation. Now I'm wondering what the best way to implement these operations is.
I'm using hashlib to calculate the hashes, but since the hashes I get are then string, how do I calculate with them?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `hexdigest()` method to get hexadecimal digits, and then convert them to a number:

```
>>> h = hashlib.md5('data')
>>> int(h.hexdigest(), 16)
188041611063492600696317361555123480284L
```

If you already have the output of `digest()`, you can convert it to hexadecimal digits:

```
>>> hexDig = ''.join('%02x' % ord(x) for x in h.digest())
>>> int(hexDig, 16)
188041611063492600696317361555123480284L
```

**Edit**:

For the second case, it's actually easier to convert using `.encode('hex')` or `binascii.hexlify`:

```
>>> int(h.digest().encode('hex'), 16)
188041611063492600696317361555123480284L
>>> int(binascii.hexlify(h.digest()), 16)
188041611063492600696317361555123480284L
```